# Play MP4 video in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-resource-packs, minecraft-addons

Is there a way to combine add-ons and scripts to have a block that plays `.mp4` videos in Minecraft Bedrock?

Comment: no, just use a normal media player, its much simpler

Comment: You can’t read files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can’t read files, and even if you could “MP4” is a broad file type for a ton of different compression methods so it isn’t really realistic for one person to do with commands/addon js anyway.